# How do compilers handle namespaces?

Tags: compiler-construction, computer-science

Let's say it's in C++. when I import or export a package into my program, what is generally going on at the compiler's level?

Does it import a new Abstract Syntax tree?
How does it affect the existing activation record?

Comment: That would surely depend on the language, and how the compiler is written.